# Microsoft Azure Active Directory cloud and on-prem AD

Tags: azure, directory, cloud

The question is- now is 2017 and just saw on [azure.microsoft.com](http://azure.microsoft.com) that AAD has now Domain Services, LDAP, AD domain join, NTLM, and Kerberos auth.

And there is a lots of publications(2014,15,16) that you can’t replace it traditional AD(server on-prem)  with cloud solution based on Azure AD. If it possible to do so, then it’s changing everything. Then I would like to compare or contrast.

I’m just would like to understand globally without technical debates.
At the Marco level or high level- **can be possible to replace AD with Azure AD?**

Answer (score 0):

No. AAD is not a replacement for AD, and doesn't have all it's capabilities.
Closest thing you have right now is AAD Domain Services. See a feature comparison here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/active-directory-ds-comparison